# Python: Integrating Data Point Curve

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, calculus

I have a list of velocities in x,y,z as well as a domain list of times corresponding to each value (the time step sizes are not constant). I am looking to integrate the curve described by these sets of data points to get the position output curve in data points. I can then offset the curve by the initial positions (constant) I have on the side.

```
times       = np.asarray([0, 0.1, 0.3, 0.5, 3])
velocity_x  = np.asarray([1,  2 ,  3 ,  4 , 5])
position_x  = _integrate_(times,velocity_x)
position_c  = 100 #Constant initial position
position_x  += position_c
```

What pythonic function (`_integrate_()`) is available for this type of calculation? I have seen some methods in scipy, however, most seem to deal with definite integrals and/or symbolic functions.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you just want a step-wise plot, this is not a hard problem, right?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def integrate( times, velocities ):
    pos = 0
    t0 = 0
    v0 = 0
    outp = [ ]
    for t,v in zip(times,velocities):
        deltat = t - t0
        pos += deltat * v0
        outp.append( pos )
        t0 = t
        v0 = v
    return outp

times       = np.asarray([0, 0.1, 0.3, 0.5, 3])
velocity_x  = np.asarray([1,  2 ,  3 ,  4 , 5])
position_x  = integrate(times,velocity_x)
print(position_x)
plt.plot( times, position_x )
plt.show()
```

Output:

```
timr@tims-gram:~/src$ python x.py
[0.0, 0.1, 0.5, 1.1, 11.1]
```

[image]